# getUserByToken at auth.service call double

Tags: metronic

I'm try using metronic today, and see that method getUserByToken at auth.service always call double, it is normal or some bug? because when we start using ajax post to populate user detail, this will call same ajax 2x.

I'm using metronic 7 with angular.

Answer (score 0):

I'm found root cause why this always double ajax

```
auth service constructor called
auth.service.ts:72 getUserByToken called
app.module.ts:23 APP_INITIALIZER appInitializer(authService: AuthService) called
auth.service.ts:72 getUserByToken called
```

in app module define APP_INITIALIZER to check token, and in constructor of class already create subscribe. But I don't know while I remove subscribe at constructor effect.